# what is a Double Pointer equivalent in c#?

Tags: c#, c++, migration, pointer-to-pointer

I'm trying to convert a c++ code into c# and I encountered a double pointer. I'm wondering how can double pointers be implemented in c#?

if I have say,

```
MyClass **MyClasses;
```

and it was initialized like this.

```
MyClasses = new MyClass*[ClassNums];
```

in another function inside the class, every subitems were initialized in a loop.

```
for(num = 0; num < classnum; num++)
{
    MyClasses[subnum] = new MyClass();
}
```

and this double-pointer is being used like this.

```
MyClasses[subnum]->MyMethod();
```

How can this be converted into c#? I tried to use an array of `MyClasses[]` but i'm not quite sure about it. Also, I cannot test this because it's from a static library and the components which are using it are not yet converted into c#. Should I use generic lists or something?

Comment: Can you give the original code, and what you have tried, a bit more code detail, I do however suggest to find away around the pointer and avoid it unless it is completely necesarry

Comment: apparently, it is being used like this

MyClasses[subnum]->MyMethod();

that's why i thought it should be a generic list.

Comment: If that is the case I suggest you try something like 
MyClasses[] list = new MyClasses[ClassNums];
And then it will be list[subnum].MyMethod();

Comment: i tried making it an array in C# but i was unsure if it's the same as double pointers in c++ since im not quite good at c++ especially pointers. as for the reason for the code conversion, we're trying to migrate an entire application from c++ to c# by following the c++ implementations as base. and of course this is due to client's request.

Comment: touché. most of us are c# devs so it's quite a challenge.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the *outer* pointer is being used to illustrate a spannable range, as shown in the loop here:

```
for(num = 0; num < classnum; num++)
{
    MyClasses[subnum] = new MyClass();
}
```

So the *outer* pointer should probably be replaced by a list, array or `IEnumerable<T>` sequence.

The *inner* pointer is being used to direct to an object, so that should be replaced with a reference.

So: unless there is something *very specific* that the C++ code is doing, all you need here is:

```
MyClass[] arr = ...
...
for(int i = 0, i < arr.Length ; i++)
{
    arr[i] = new MyClass();
}
...
arr[i].MyMethod();
```

---

Note that this can only be interpreted by *looking at the code*. There are other possible ways to talk about "double pointers*; consider this `ref` example:

```
void SomeMethod(ref MyClass obj) {...}
```

Here `obj` is a reference to a reference (to a `MyClass`)–with everything being double-dereferenced automatically (or a single-dereferencing assignment if you change the value of `obj`). This too would be comparable to a double-pointer.